# grep the result of cdrecord or wodim

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I would like to parse the result/progress of a running `cdrecord -v` burn process. What I tried so far was `cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -data foo.iso 2>&1 | grep -E 'Track [0-9]+:.*written'`.

Unfortunately, the command above won't show anything until the burning is completed. I think this is due to the fact that cdrecord/wodim uses a carriage return (CR) in order to show the progress in the same line.

At the end of the burning process, only the following line is shown:

```
Track 01: Total bytes read/written: 98211840/98211840 (47955 sectors).
```

Is there any way to grep this kind of information?

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`tr` did the trick!

`cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -data foo.iso 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -E 'Track [0-9]+:.*written'`